# Proxy setting not changed when closing application after using fiddlercore

Tags: c#, winforms, registry, fiddler

I'm using fiddlercore in one of my application, but problem is that when I exit application and use this code to exit application

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
}
```

I'm unable to connect to internet. Here is the screenshot of my registry after exiting application.(And i'm using fiddlercore proxy while submitting this question as i'm not able to use my internet without fiddlercore)[image]

Comment: Have you verified that the line in question is actually getting hit in ALL cases? The primary thing that function does is restore your proxy settings to the default. To manually correct your proxy settings when FiddlerCore isn't running, in IE, click Tools > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings.

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes the problem was with my proxy settings which I have solved by reading this article. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2289942

Answer (score 0):

`FiddlerApplication.Shutdown()` must be used with care especially you have to ensure no traffic is being send at shutdown time.

To reliably get the proxy settings back to default, de-attach proxy instead like

`FiddlerApplication.oProxy.Detach();`